# Cannot find file and compress using ffmpeg exec in PHP

Tags: php, file, ffmpeg, compression

I'm trying to compress files with ffmpeg but despite having the correct file path it cannot find the file:

I'm using this code here:

```
echo $ypath;
exec("ffmpeg -i ".$ypath." -vf 'scale=iw/3:ih/3' ".$prevPath ." 2>&1", $error);
foreach($error as $next) {
    echo "<br>".$next;
}
```

And get this result:

```
../data/mydirectory/buffer/1610997353779_D012&ForestDescend.mp4
sh: 1: ForestDescend.mp4: not found
```

What's the problem, why can't it find the file in question. I'm 100% sure the path is correct because I'm using it further above the code to convert images who are in the same directory.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ampersand (`&`) in the filename is probably causing the issue. A simple way around this is to wrap the `$ypath` value in quotes:

```
exec('ffmpeg -i "'.$ypath.'" -vf "scale=iw/3:ih/3" "'.$prevPath .'" 2>&1', $error);
```

Combine this with [`escapeshellarg()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) if your filenames might contain quotes or other special characters.

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much that it was the `&` that was causing the issue.. However I copy pasted your solution and it causes a PHP error - something must be wrong with your syntax..

Comment: Yep I had the quotes in the wrong order around $prevpath.